# Access class method via Vue 3 + Vuex state + Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Is it possible to access class methods via Vuex state?

In the following situation, I want to call `fullName()` to display the user's formatted name.

`TypeError: store.state.user.fullName is not a function`

**Classes**

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public id: string = '',
        public first_name: string = '',
        public last_name: string = '',
    ) {}

    fullName = (format: 'forward' | 'reverse' = 'forward') => {
        if (format === 'forward') return `${this.first_name} ${this.last_name}`
        if (format === 'reverse') return `${this.last_name}, ${this.first_name}`
    }
}
export interface RootState {
    user: User
}
```

**Vuex**

```
export const key: InjectionKey<Store<RootState>> = Symbol()

export default createStore<RootState>({
    strict: true,
    state: {
        user: new User(),
    },
})
```

**Component**

```
setup(){
    const state = useState(key)
    return {
        name: computed(_ => store.state.user.fullName('forward'))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, Vuex strips out class methods, only storing its plain values.

My workaround to recover the class methods was to copy the Vuex User state into a new instance of User.

```
const user = computed(_ => Object.assign(new User(), store.state.user))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it strips them, I'm unaware of this behaviour and suspect that you did something wrong on your side. The class went wrong and you shouldn't use it at all. fullName is instance method for no good reason and is hard-coded to use non-reactive properties on `this`, check how `fullName =` sugar syntax really works.